# Derivation of Yurke-Stoler state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics, non-linear-optics, schroedingers-cat

The evolution of a coherent state $\vert\alpha\rangle$ in a Kerr-nonlinear medium $H=\Omega (a^\dagger a)^2$ is given by
$$
\vert \psi(t) \rangle = e^{-\vert\alpha\vert^2/2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\alpha^n}{\sqrt{n!}} e^{-i n^2 \Omega t} \vert n\rangle \;.
$$
For $\Omega t = \pi/2$ it was proven that [Yurke, Stoler]
$$
\vert \psi(t) \rangle = \dfrac{(1-i)}{2} \left( \vert\alpha\rangle + i \vert-\alpha\rangle \right) \;.
$$
How is this equality derived exactly?